# Trigger button from hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I want to display the __button when I hover over the __image. But right now, the button has its own hover. It should do this: when the hover from __image is triggered, raise opacity of __button to visible.

Thanks for any help!

```
&__image {
    display:grid
    &:hover {
        transition: 1s;
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
}

&__button {
    opacity: 0;
    display: grid;
    &:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sry for the stupid question, but what does the `__image` selector select? It doesn't look like an identifier-, class-, attribute-, element- or pseudo-selector.

Comment: SO's editor currently does not recognize SCSS. But FWIW, what you're trying to do might be better experimented with on CodePen.

Comment: Yes, of course. My mistake. There is a parent class .item that wraps &__image and &__button.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I found one solution.

```
&__image {
    display:grid
    &:hover {
        transition: 1s;
        transform: scale(1.05);
       .button {
               opacity: 1;
            }
    }
}

&__button {
    opacity: 0;
    display: grid;
}
```

And then in js: className="item__music button item__button"

Answer (score 0):

If this is the layout of your HTML

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="__image" style="height:200px;width: 200px;background-color:red;margin:20px"></div>
  <div class="__button" style="height:200px;width: 200px;background-color:red;margin:20px"></div>
</div>
```

Then this style should do it:

```
.item {
  .__image {
    display: grid;
    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 1s;
      transform: scale(1.05);
      + .__button {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }

  .__button {
    opacity: 0;
    display: grid;
    &:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```